# ImportError: No module named backend_tkagg

Tags: python, numpy, module, pycharm, python-module

I have such imports and code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    


#Read the data from pydatasets repo using Pandas
url = './file.csv'
white_side = pd.read_csv(url)    
#Fitting the model    
model = sm.ols(formula='budget ~ article_size',
               data=white_side,
               subset=white_side['producer'] == "Peter Jackson")
fitted = model.fit()
print fitted.summary()
```

After execution of this code I have such errors:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/seth/PycharmProjects/osiris_project/PMN_way/start.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/seth/PycharmProjects/osiris_project/PMN_way/start.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
ImportError: No module named backend_tkagg

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I`m using openSUSE and pycharm community edition latest version with installed pandas, numpy, etc
How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've seen this before, also on openSUSE (12.3).  The fix is to edit the default matplotlibrc file.

Here's how you find where the default matplotlibrc file lives, and where it lives on my machine:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc'
```

The backend setting is the first configuration option in this file.  Change it from `TkAgg` to `Agg`, or to some other backend you have installed on your system.  The comments in the matplotlibrc file list all backends supported by matplotlib.

The backend specified in this file is only the default; you can still change it at runtime by adding the following two lines, *before any other matplotlib import*:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")  # or whichever backend you wish to use
```

Comment: Good answer. Official matplotlib config example: http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: This didn't work for me.  However, I was able to fix the error by importing the backend module before importing matplotlib.pyplot.  See my answer.  I expect there is a better solution than mine that involves specifying the path to the backend modules.

Answer (score 8):

I use openSuse 13.1 and had the same error "ImportError: No module named backend_tkagg".

I solved it by using this suggestion: http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/416182-Python-matplolib.

I've installed the python-matplotlib-tk package, and now it is working just fine.

E.g. you can use: `zypper install python-matplotlib-tk`

Answer (score 7):

I tried various solutions, only this works for me:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

Answer (score 4):

I add my answer for those who might encounter this problem using CARLA Simulator.

Using Python 3.6, and installing matplotlib v 2.2.5 solved this problem for me.

To remove matplotlib and install the right version you can run

`pip uninstall -r requirements.txt`

Then add `matplotlib==2.2.5` to the requirement file and run `pip install -r requirements.txt --user` to install the correct versions.

If you are missing the requirements.txt file, here you are

```
Pillow>=3.1.2
numpy>=1.14.5
protobuf>=3.6.0
pygame>=1.9.4
matplotlib==2.2.5
future>=0.16.0
scipy>=0.17.0
```

In case you have different python versions and you would like to use a specific python version using `py -<version>` will use the right python version.

***WARNING:*** Changing Path variable of the current Python version might be dangerous and specially for linux users it might cause that you can not open the terminal again. This is because different Python versions might not be compatible with the current pip version you are using. If it is too late for you and you already messed up with your terminal you can visit This [tutorial](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-cannot-open-terminal/) to fix your issue.

After all of the fixes you might still get this error:

`TypeError: blit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'colormode'`

So you might want to edit the `live_plotter.py` file and remove `colormode` attribute from all the lines which are passing it to `blit()` method.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by putting

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg
```

above

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Note, I received the same error while trying to run an executable generated using `Py2exe`.

Here is what I got when I ran TheProgram.exe from the command prompt:

```
>>TheProgram.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ThePythonScriptToMakeIntoExe.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg'
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before, I solved it by using an old version of matplotlib which is version 3.0.0
if you don't have this version try `pip install matplotlib==3.0.0`
hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue while doing live plotting using the **2.2.2** version. Tried the following:

`pip install matplotlib==3.0.0 --user`

It's still an older version but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the variable before starting python

```
export MPLBACKEND=Agg; python3
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7115/#issuecomment-389369332).