# Creating a cross-platform GUI in Python 3.4

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am building a GUI that can take .txt or .xlsx files as input, performs some operations on them and returns the results as plots. I am using Python 3.4 and Tkinter 8.5 for the GUI.

It has a drop-down list for selecting the file type and a button for opening a dialog box to select the file. It then saves the contents of the file to a different file in the same directory. It also has a button to quit the program and a text box and a label which I was just playing with and do not serve any purpose.

The GUI works when I run the `datagui.py` file. However I also want to make a cross-platform file that will not need Python to run it. I was using cx_freeze for this purpose to make an exe and wrote the following setup.py file to build it (available on the cx_Freeze website too):

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
   base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "datagui",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My first GUI application",
        executables = [Executable("datagui.py", base=base)])
```

When I try to run the `datagui.exe` file located in the `...\build\exe.win-amd64-3.4` directory, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "datagui.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Anish\Desktop\DR. DIXON\Data Analysis\python codes\dataselect.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 274, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are using matlplotlib?

Comment: "I also want to make a cross-platform executable". But Linux and Mac can't run executables.

Comment: I was using matplotlib and numpy in a seperate program for which I imported the pylab. I copied parts of the code in a seperate module which I am using now, and this one uses numpy but not matplotlib. Do you think that might be the problem here.

Comment: Kevin - That was a phrasing problem there. I meant to say a GUI app that is executable in multiple platforms. I am trying to make an exe as of now.

Comment: @Anish No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg'

Comment: @Anish try adding `build_exe_options = {"packages": [“matplotlib"]}` to the setup file

Comment: @Rishav - I imported the numpy module instead of the pylab module, and now the exe works fine! Is it because I imported matplotlib but did not use it?

Comment: @Anish I have no clue, I have not used either cxfreeze, or numpy, or matplotlib before :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out your `matplotlib` configuration.

[See this previous answer on matplotlib import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582384/importerror-no-module-named-backend-tkagg)

You need to indicate the type of back-end you want matplotlib to implement.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. I figured I don't need to import pylab anyway, so only importing numpy works for my GUI. I can now run it from the exe.