# Python file can't import matplotlib despite numerous installations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to run the CARLA simulator but I'm constantly getting this error.

```
  File "module_7.py", line 32, in <module>
    import live_plotter as lv   # Custom live plotting library
  File "/opt/CarlaSimulator/PythonClient/live_plotter.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.tkagg'
```

These are the imports in the file live_plotter.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame
```

I've tried to install matplotlib numerous times but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Try opening your command prompt in administrator mode and first of all uninstall matplotlib and then toggle a fresh install for matplotlib

Comment: Do any of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582384/importerror-no-module-named-backend-tkagg) help?

Comment: Have you tried importing matplotlib first then `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`

Comment: @AshlinJP When I do that, I get the `NameError: name 'tkagg' is not defined` error

Comment: And when I do `tkagg = matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`, I get this error: `tkagg.blit(photo, fca.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit'`

Comment: Can you check your backend by `print(matplotlib.get_backend())`. If not TkAgg may be hardset following this https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7115/#issuecomment-389369332   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasAgg
```

It works for me.

Comment: This is still relevant as of Oct 2022.