# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_svg' when running exe from pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I want to compile a python file to a standalone .exe programm using pyinstaller onefile. Running the python file, everything works fine, but running the .exe file, it throws the exception

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_svg'

I am using [schemdraw](https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/),
and schemdraw uses matplotlib.

Because I dont want matplotlib to open a window everytime I export an svg I use the backend "Agg" with matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

---

- I of course have tried reinstalling matplotlib
- Using instead of pyinstaller `--onefile <file>` `pyinstaller <file>`
- I tried putting `import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg` over `import matplotlip`
- upgrading matplotlib `pip install matplotlib --upgrade --user`
  basicly [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582384/importerror-no-module-named-backend-tkagg). But since this isn't exactly my problem and none of it worked I am asking here

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use Matplotlib for anything other than schemdraw? If not, you can set schemdraw to draw straight to SVG:

```
schemdraw.use('svg')
```

then it won't even go through Matplotlib.

Comment: No I don't have to use Matplotlib. But can you please either link a documentation or elaborate on the use? on `schemdraw.use('svg')` I can't find the documentation.
Thanks

Comment: [Documentation](https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/backends.html#svg-backend). Works the same as the default Matplotlib backend; use either Drawing.save() or Drawing.get_imagedata() to get the svg as bytes.